# Como convertir un .jar a un app en Mac

Tags: java

Buenas tardes desearia saber como puedo convertir un ejecutable `.jar` en un app para `Mac`. Mi programa es un GUI el cual se puede comunicar con una base de datos remota, para ello necesita una libreria(`mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar`).

Por favor diganme como puedo convertirlo.

Comment: Cabe resaltar que no creo que se pueda utilizar jar Bundler

Comment: Por qué no ejecutas el jar como en cualquier plataforma?

Comment: Tanto como convertirlo no puedes, al menos eso creo, lo que si se puede es incluirlo dentro de la estructura de carpetas del .app y mediante *shell script* + un *info.plist* ponerle un icono y correrlo, naturalmente eso no le da una característica nativa sino que es otra forma de llamar al *jar* mediante *scripts*.

Comment: pero lo que quiero saber es si se puede correr como un .app un .jar; simplemente diganme como, por favor

Comment: No, el jar que dices no es "Runnable" por lo que aunque lo convirtieras no funcionaria. Necesita un punto de inicio.

Comment: Lo que deseas es empaquetar tu .jar en un fichero .app? Así como la opción que empaquetaba el jre y el .jar en un .exe para poder ejecutarlo sin la necesidad de instalar la jvm.

Comment: quiero que mi .jar se pueda ejecutar en una mac como app sin que esa mac tenga instalado java